# Removing image/file name from path in android

Tags: android, relative-path

I have selected a file from a folder on the SD card, now I want to get that path without the file name attached, here is the code to how I am doing it:

```
currImageURI = data.getData();
String name=getRealPathFromURI(currImageURI);
```

now name stores all the path like /mnt/sdcard/images/photo1.jpg.
I want to remove photo1.jpg form this path, need help with this aspect thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use this:

```
String path = new File(name).getParent();
```